# Why would trait's val be evaluated if it is overridden in class?

Tags: scala

```
scala> trait A { val a = { println("i'm invoked"); "1" } }
defined trait A

scala> class B extends A { override val a = { println("i'm invoked B"); "2" } }
defined class B

scala> (new B).a
i'm invoked
i'm invoked B
res0: String = 2
```

How can I avoid the `val a` in `trait A` being evaluated? I tried using `lazy val` and that works, but would be interested in knowing if there's an alternative way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in this [Scala doc](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/initialization-order.html):

> Initialization of strict vals is done in the following order:
>
> 1. Superclasses are fully initialized before subclasses.
> 2. Otherwise, in declaration order.

The clause "fully initialized before" explains why a strict `val` is evaluated despite being overriden in the subclass.

Besides `lazy val`, an alternative is to replace `val` with `def` in your trait:

```
trait A { def a = { println("i'm invoked"); "1" } }
class B extends A { override def a = { println("i'm invoked B"); "2" } }

(new B).a
// i'm invoked B
// res1: String = 2
```

Comment: The answer to the question must be "side effects", since a pure computation would be discarded. The spec is not satisfying on this score: "Furthermore, stats may in any case also contain expressions; these are executed in the order they are given as part of the initialization of a template." Statements include definitions.